# Asp.net core upload file size is wrong

Tags: asp.net, angular, file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc

I wrote a file upload function with asp.net Core and I call this function with Angular httpclient
But the problem is that the file size on the server side is bigger and when it is saved, the file gets corrupted

**For example, an image file with a size of 43 kilobytes becomes 79 kilobytes on the server side**

**It can be said that the size of the files is doubled**

**And that files larger than 30 MB do not have this problem**

api

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost("[action]") ]
    [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 309715200)]
    [RequestSizeLimit(309715200)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file )
    {
        try
        {       
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.CopyTo(ms);
                    var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                   var filelist =  _fileManager.SaveFile(file.FileName,fileBytes);
                    if (filelist == null)
                        return BadRequest();
                    return Ok(new {
                        nofile = filelist.StreamId
                });                  
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
        }
    }
```

angular

```js
UploadFile(file:any ): Observable<any>
    {
        
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers = headers.set(
                'Content-Type',
                 'multipart/form-data;'
            );

        return    this._httpClient
            .post(this.uploadUrl,formData,{ reportProgress: true, observe: 'events' }
            )

    }
```

Comment: I created a sample angular app and couldn't reproduce the issue. Also headers isn't used by your http post so deleted my answer. I would check how you're verifying the file length and whether you have a proxy / middleware setup that could be interfering.

Comment: My problem is solved
I had a middleware that replaced a series of characters, and disabling it solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved I had a middleware that replaced a series of characters, and disabling it solved the problem